# zsh vared: how to define custom completion?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, interactive

I would like to launch a command that would read user input and pass each line as a new task to TaskWarrior:

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -e

while vared -p 'task add> ' -eca task; do eval task add "${task[@]}"; done
```

Now I would like to have the `vared` input line to have access to any relevant `task add` completions – the input/completion should behave the same as if I had a regular shell and already typed `task add` into it.

I tried messing around with the `$words` parameter, but got no discernable effect.